# Database Connection Management

Tags: java, jdbc

I am in the process of designing a simple Java application which deals with insert/delete/update of records in a MySQL database using JDBC. I have a class `Member` which deals with the member's details.

```
class Member {
  ... // Private Members
  ... // Accessors
}
```

..and I have a handler to deal with the member records

```
class MemberHandler {
  public MemberHandler(){...}
  public void addMember(Member mem){...}
  public void removeMember(Member mem){...}
  public Member[] getMembers(){...}
}
```

All I am worried about is the method in which I establish connection to the database and disconnect. I can do it in two ways -

**Method 1:**
I can have a member in MemberHandler `Connection conn`, establish connection while instantiating the class and close the connection when the object is no more needed. Here I would have a connection per object and I need not establish a connection whenever I need to do any database related activity. In this case, the disadvantage seems to be - when there is a loss in network connection, `conn` could become invalid.

```
class MemberHandler {
  private java.sql.Connection conn;
  ... // Other members
  private void createConnection(){/*creates the connection*/}
  private void closeConnection(){conn.close(); /*called when conn is no more needed*/}
}
```

**Method 2:**
I can establish a connection when needed and close it when I am done with the activity. Disadvantage: everytime, I need to establish a connection and close it. For eg.,

```
...
...
private void addMember() {
  //establish connection
  //update database
  //close connection
}
...
...
```

Which of these two ways seems to be better? Or is there a third better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to go for [connection-pooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool)

- [c3po](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/)